# Django makemessages doesn't see locales in locale_paths

Tags: python, linux, django, django-i18n

I have custom locale path in my settings

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'templates','v1','locale'),
)
```

but when i'm trying to create .po files, i've get error:

```
$ python manage.py makemessages --locale=ru
CommandError: This script should be run from the Django Git tree or your project or app tree. If you did indeed run it from the Git checkout or your project or application, maybe you are just missing the conf/locale (in the django tree) or locale (for project and application) directory? It is not created automatically, you have to create it by hand if you want to enable i18n for your project or application.
```

Why django doesn't want to use LOCALE_PATHS?

Absolute paths are:
PROJECT_ROOT = '/home/creotiv/ENVS/project_env/project/project'
LOCALE_PATHS = ('/home/creotiv/ENVS/project_env/project/project/templates/v1/locale')

PS: Also i added translation to main app and django doesnt see it either.

Comment: You generally use __django-admin__ makemessages . CommandError sometimes genreated by this. Try as it is told in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) with proper commands.

Also you may check [makemessages docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#makemessages) too

Comment: Can you add absolute paths of the 'project root', manage.py, settings.py and 'locale' folder?

Comment: @SencerH. Added paths

Answer (score 2):

*First things first;* You need to give correct path of the `manage.py` to the python.

```
$ python /path/to/the/manage.py makemessages --locale=ru
```

Or go to directory which is included `manage.py`. After that run that command you've wrote in your question.

```
$ python manage.py makemessages --locale=ru
```

*Next;* Did you create `./templates/v1/locale` directories under the project home?

According to error you may check existence of the `./templates/v1/locale'` folder.

*Also;* You may need to append `LANGUAGES` setting in to project `settings.py` file:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),  # (Optional)
)
```

Appendix:

If you are developing under virtual environment, do not forget to enable virtual environment first.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to go inside the app or project directory. Try this:

```
$ ls  # should return also the manage.py
$ cd myproject
$ ls  # should return also the settings.py
$ python ../manage.py makemessages --locale=ru
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updated to django 1.7 and problem gone.

Comment: That's odd. Which version did you use before update?

Comment: 1.6.4 i think(i'm not remember)